# Identify/preserve the original creation/modification time of an uploaded image in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to store the original creation/modification time of an uploaded imaged with my ImageField in Django. However, since the uploaded image is an in-memory-file, it doesn't seem to contain such information. After the file is saved in the MEDIA_ROOT directory, the timestamps of the saved file are the creation/modification time when it is saved, instead of the original ones.

Is there a way to preserve the timestamp after uploaded, or extract the original timestamps?

```
photo = request.FILES['photo']
my_model.photo = photo
my_model.creation_time = get_photo_creation_time(photo)  # How to get the original time?
my_model.save()
```

Or is there a trick in the browser side to do it?
p.s. ActiveX is not an option

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to try and read the EXIF data of the image?
The [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/tutorial.html) module is pretty good for this. You should probably make sure you are not using the `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` arguments on your `Photo.creation_time` model field too.

Comment: Thank you! I tried extracting EXIF with django-photofile but I guess I must have done something wrong so I thought I could tried the creation time from file instead. I ended up using EXIF.py and successfully retrieve the time from EXIF. Thanks!